# Null Pointer Exception in Linked List

Tags: java

I'm making a program that can recursively add Polynomials (represented by Linked Lists) together. But I keep getting a null pointer exception in the line `if (p1.data.exp == p2.data.exp) {`

I've tried debugging by setting both terms to either one or the other, but I keep getting the error (does this mean that they are both null?). I don't see how this can happen since it should return before getting to this part if they are null.
Does anyone have suggestions?

Main:

```
public class Polynomial {

    private Node poly;


    public Polynomial(){
    poly = new Node();
    }

    private Polynomial(Node node){
    poly = node;
    }
    public void addTerm(int coef, int exp){
    Term term = new Term(coef, exp);
    Node node = new Node(term, null);

    Node iterator = poly;

    //if the list is empty just add the node
    if (poly.next == null){
        System.out.println("poly.next is null. adding node to first pos.");
        poly.next = node;
        return;
    }

    //if list isn't empty find the appropriate spot for it
    while (iterator.next != null){
        System.out.println("iterator.next != null...");
        if (exp < iterator.next.data.exp){
        System.out.println("\texp < iterator.next.data.exp");
        node.next = iterator.next;
        iterator.next = node;
        return;
        }
        if (exp == iterator.next.data.exp){
        System.out.println("\texp == iterator.next.data.exp");
        iterator.next.data.coef += coef;
        return;
        }
        iterator = iterator.next;
    }

    //if we get to this point then the list isn't empty
    //and it doesn't fit inside the list, hence it must
    //be added to the end of the list
    System.out.println("list wasn't empty, didn't fit inside");
    iterator.next = node;
    return;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    Node iterator = poly;
    String out = "";

    if (poly.next == null){
        return out;
    }
    while(iterator.next != null){
        out += iterator.next.data.coef;
        out += "*x^";
        out += iterator.next.data.exp;
        out += " + ";
        iterator = iterator.next;
    }
    return out.substring(0, out.lastIndexOf('+'));
    }



    public Polynomial addPolynomial (Polynomial that){
    Polynomial ret = new Polynomial();

    Polynomial iterator = this;

    return new Polynomial(addPolys(this.poly, that.poly));
    }

    public Node addPolys(Node p1, Node p2) {
    // If P1 is null, just use P2
    if (p1 == null) {
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = null;
    }

    // if P1 is still null, no P2 either so finished
    if (p1 == null) return null;

    Node ret = new Node();

    // if P2 is null now, just one poly remains
    if (p2 == null) {
        ret.data = p1.data;
        p1 = p1.next;
    } else {

        // do we combine nodes?
        if (p1.data.exp == p2.data.exp) {
            ret.data = new Term(p1.data.coef + p2.data.coef, p1.data.exp
                    + p2.data.exp);
            p1 = p1.next;
            p2 = p2.next;
        } else {
            // we just copy a node

            // make p1 the bigger exponent
            if (p1.data.exp < p2.data.exp) {
                Node t = p1;
                p1 = p2;
                p2 = t;
            }

            ret.data = p1.data;
            p1 = p1.next;
        }
    }

    ret.next = addPolys(p1, p2);
    return ret;
}

    /*
     * Term
     */
    private class Term implements Comparable{
    int coef;
    int exp;

    public int getCoef() {
        return coef;
    }

    public void setCoef(int coef) {
        this.coef = coef;
    }

    public int getExp() {
        return exp;
    }

    public void setExp(int exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public Term(int coef, int exp) {
        this.coef = coef;
        this.exp = exp;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object rhs){
        Term that = (Term)rhs;
        return this.exp - that.exp;
    }
    }//end Term


    /*
     * Node
     */
    private class Node{
    Term data;
    Node next;

    public Term getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Term data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node() {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(Term data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    }//end Node
}
```

Test:

```
public class Polynomials {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial();
        Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial();
        Polynomial p0 = new Polynomial();
        p1.addTerm(1, 2);
        p1.addTerm(1, 4);
        p1.addTerm(1, 6);
    p2.addTerm(1, 1);
    p2.addTerm(1, 3);
    p2.addTerm(1, 5);
    System.out.println("p1 = " + p1.toString());
    System.out.println("p2 = " + p2.toString());

    System.out.println("Adding p1 to p2...");
    p0 = p1.addPolynomial(p2);
    System.out.println(p0.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `p1` and `p2` may be non-null, but what about `p1.data` and `p2.data`? And, BTW, there is no `(p1.data.exponent == p2.data.exponent)` in the code you posted.

Comment: FYI, it's not really removed since you can still look at the previous versions and look at the code anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this part

```
if (p1.data.exp == p2.data.exp)
```

property 'data' or 'exp' is null.

I'll give an advice write your code more protective:

1. use getter and setter method;
2. don't use chain of references (eg, p1.data.exp);
3. test 'null' case;
4. add log infromation;

bye

Comment: `exp` being null wont cause an NPE... Looks like `data` is the culprit (as mentiined elsewhere).

Comment: it's true, I've answered too fast

Answer (score 1):

One of the `data` fields in the `Node` object is not initialized. My guess is that this is setting the data to null.

```
Node node = new Node(term, null);
```

So any node variable that references that object will throw an exception when you do `p1.data.exponent`.

Comment: Hmm, this does look like the culprit. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: @dtbravo: Make sure there is a `Term` object for the node before you access it or disallow the creation of a `Node` without a `Term` object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `p1.data` or `p2.data` is `null`, so you can't obtain the exponent from it.